# How big I need to make a greenhouse vertical farm to accomodate the equivalent of 7 acres?

Tags: vegetables, greenhouse, urban-gardening

So, I know that "vertical farming" is a broad term, and there are dozen ways of making a vertical farm with a dozen of different techniques to grow plants. And before I try to search for the details on how to make and grow all of that, first I want to know if the space displacement is even practical (or if the plants would grow anyway in these conditions).

So, what I'm looking to try is to plant vegetables and greens in pots (I heard that you need at least a pot/sack of 40 liters to grow potatoes) and stack then in columns or shelves inside of a greenhouse, so they can receive as much as sunlight they need with ideal temperatures.

[image: Advertisement for aeroponic plant holders]

I know that this is a different way of planting (aeroponic), but it would be something among these lines.

I [saw that](https://permaculturism.com/how-much-land-does-it-take-to-feed-one-person/#:%7E:text=A%20person%20needs%20about%205,comfortably%2C%20producing%20their%20own%20food.) to feed a single adult human being with only the food grown in a farm, you would need a farm of the size around of **7 acres**.

So the list of questions:

1. How much space it would be needed between the 2m/6,56f tall (or higher if needed) columns/shelves, so the plants can receive enough sunlight?
2. How much space I would need to fit all of these columns? It would need to be as big as a farm?